# ubuntu 17.04 usb installation asking for username and password

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, 17.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 17.04 through a bootable usb drive.. But as the system boots, the ubuntu loin screen is shown and it asks for username and password. Can't go further.

Comment: Try username "ubuntu" and leave the password empty.